# CreateView set foreign key from URL parameter

Tags: python, django

I want to be able to create a lorum, using a ipsum_id (ForeignKey) that has been supplied in the URL. Using Django's class based views.

Given the following URL:

```
url(r'^lorem/create/ipsum/(?P<ipsum_id>\d+)/$', LoremCreateView.as_view(), name='create'),
```

I have the following view:

```
class LoremCreateView(CreateView):
    """ Allow a user to create a Lorem. """
    model = Lorem
    ...

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """ Get context variables for rendering the template. """
        ipsum = get_object_or_404(Ipsum, pk=self.kwargs['ipsum_id'])
        kwargs['ipsum'] = ipsum
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        """ Save the form instance. """
        ipsum = get_object_or_404(Ipsum, pk=self.kwargs['ipsum_id'])
        form.instance.ipsum = ipsum
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

This works fine, however I don't like the fact I call `get_object_or_404` twice.

Is there a better way of doing this?

It might be possible to override an appropriate method and set `self.ipsum` - not sure I like doing this either.

Also is `get_object_or_404` appropriate here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to add the `ipsum` instance to the template context unless it's used in the template. Adding things to `self` is the cleanest way.

Using `get_object_or_404` is appropriate if we *require* the `ipsum` instance to exist in order to save a `lorem`.

You should end up with something like this:

```
# urls.py

from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('lorem/create/ipsum/<int:ipsum_id>/', LoremCreateView.as_view(), name='create'),
]
```

```
# views.py

class LoremCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Lorem

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Overridden so we can make sure the `Ipsum` instance exists
        before going any further.
        """
        self.ipsum = get_object_or_404(Ipsum, pk=kwargs['ipsum_id'])
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        """
        Overridden to add the ipsum relation to the `Lorem` instance.
        """
        form.instance.ipsum = self.ipsum
        return super().form_valid(form)
```